# Difference between 'record for' and 'record in'

Tags: prepositions, licensing

In an english exercise, there was the correct answer:

> I am going to establish a new record **for** swimming.

However, my gut wants to write 'record **in** swimming' (as it is written in Wikipedia: 'list of world records *in* swimming').  Google gives both versions: *world record **in** smth* and *world record **for** smth*.

Which is the correct version or what is the difference?

Comment: you would also establish a new record for confidence saying that :)

Answer (score 1):

They are both correct. However, it depends on where you are with regard to how English is used.  For instance, if you Google the definition for, "bollocks," you'll see what it means. In part of the English speaking world this is used as a form of curse word (albeit a light one).  However, in other parts of the English speaking world, they'll have absolutely no idea what that word means, even if they had heard it.

The difference is really semantics. They both mean the same thing in this case from a communication point of view and will only be wrong if the version you use is not consistent with where you are.